# How to navigate to Rust sources in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I have code something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}
```

... and I'm want to dive into source of `Debug`.

In IntelliJ IDEA I'm put cursor on `Debug` and pressing `cmd + b` navigates me to Rust sources.

In VSCode I'm trying to get behavior like in IDEA:

- put cursor on the same place (middle of on `Debug` word)
- open right-click menu
- press `Go to definition (F12)` or `Go to Implementations(cmd + F12)`

And VSCode shows me message `No definition found for 'Debug'`.

Is there a way to set up navigation by sources in VSCode like in IDEA?

I use [this Rust extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust) in VSCode.

Comment: _"but nothing happens"_ Do you mean that the operations appear when right-clicking and they do nothing? Or that they do not appear at all? Have you searched and installed the necessary extensions? Which ones?

Comment: Added info to the question, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the [rust-analizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer) extension, ctrl + click on Debug and it should work.
If you are using the Rust extension I advice you against it as it was abandoned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You have to disable and reenable rust-analyzer when you want it to work.

Comment: you need to use the file in lib.rs or main.rs as mod